# Inner join doub

Tags: sql, oracle, dbeaver

I have a problem with inner join:

```
SELECT 
    m.MATRICULA, m.DATA, m.VERSAO, p.MATRICULA, p.DATA, p.VERSAO 
FROM
    TBL_MY_TBL m
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         MATRICULA, MAX(p.DATA) DATA, VERSAO
     FROM 
         TBL_MY_TBL p
     GROUP BY 
         MATRICULA, VERSAO) ON m.MATRICULA = p.MATRICULA AND m.data = p.data;
```

When I run the code, I get this error:

> SQL Error [904] [42000]: ORA-00904: "P"."data": identificador inválido

Comment: Your are missing the table alias after the subquery.  It should end with `) p`.

Answer (score 0):

name you subquery like so:

```
SELECT m.MATRICULA, m.DATA, m.VERSAO, p.MATRICULA, p.DATA, p.VERSAO 
FROM TBL_MY_TBL m
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT MATRICULA, max(p.DATA) DATA, VERSAO
        FROM TBL_MY_TBL p
        GROUP BY 
            MATRICULA
            , VERSAO
        ) p
ON m.MATRICULA = p.MATRICULA 
AND m.data = p.data;
```

Comment: I don't understand what the difference for my code, sorry

Comment: If you look at the end of du query that you are joining I have it an alias name ‘p’

Comment: Humm, understood, ty!


I used your code, but this error happens SQL Error [904] [42000]: ORA-00904: "P"."DATA"